# CSS - Right and bottom border of Grid and Property Panel not showing up in Print Preview

Tags: javascript, css, extjs, extjs4, extjs4.2

Good day. I have a web application and there's a part where I programatically print a form with a Grid Panel and Property Grid on button press. My Grids both show complete borders when I view them in the browser. However, the print preview dialog does not show the right and bottom border of my Grids.

To be clear, it's the far right and far bottom borders that are not showing up - the borders between the column headers and between the header and the rows show up.

I used the `@media` CSS Query but so far, it's only worked on showing the background of the column headers of both my grids. I have a feeling I'm doing something wrong in my CSS.

Here is the code I use for the Grid Panel CSS:

```
@media all{
    .receiptGrid .x-grid-body{ 
        border-left: thin solid black;
        border-right: thin solid black;
        border-bottom: thin solid black;
        border-top: thin solid black;

        padding: 0px;
    }

    .receiptGrid .x-grid-header-ct{ 
        border: 0px;

        border-top: 0.5px solid #000000;
        border-bottom: 0.5px solid #000000;
        border-right: 1px solid #000000;

        padding: 0px;
    }

    .receiptGrid .x-grid-header-ct .x-box-inner .x-column-header-inner{ 
        border: 0px;

        border-top: 0.5px solid #000000;
        border-bottom: 0.5px solid #000000;
        border-left: thin solid #000;

        background: lightgray;
        padding: 0px;
        margin: 0px;

        font-size: 11px; 
        font-weight: bold;
        font-family: 'Arial';
        text-align: center;
        -webkit-print-color-adjust:exact;

    }

}
```

And this is the code I use for the CSS of the Property Grid:

```
@media all{
    .propGrid .x-grid-cell {
        border-right: thin solid black;
    }


    /* This changes the CSS for the AMOUNT Column */   
    .propGrid .x-grid-cell-value {
        text-align: right !important;
        font-size: 17px; 
        font-weight: bold; 
        font-style: italic; 
        font-family: 'Times New Roman';

        line-height: normal;
        border-right: thin solid black;
    }

    /* This changes the CSS for the AMOUNT Column DISABLED */   
    .propGrid .x-grid-cell-value .x-item-disabled{
        background:  white;

        text-align: right !important;
        font-size: 17px; 
        font-weight: bold; 
        font-style: italic; 
        font-family: 'Times New Roman';

        line-height: normal;
        border-right: thin solid black;

    }

    /* This changes the CSS for the MODE Column */
    .propGrid .x-grid-cell-name {
        font-size: 11px; 
        font-weight: bold;
        font-family: 'Arial';
        text-align: center !important;
        vertical-align: center;
        border-right: thin solid black;
    }

    /* This changes the header text */
    .propGrid .x-column-header-inner {


        border-left: thin solid black;
        border-bottom: thin solid black;
        border-top: thin solid black;

        padding: 0px;

        font-size: 11px; 
        font-weight: bold;
        font-family: 'Arial';
        text-align: center;
        vertical-align: center;
    }

    .propGrid .x-grid-body{ 
        border-left: thin solid black;
        border-bottom: thin solid black;
        border-top: thin solid black;
        border-right: thin solid black;


        padding: 0px;
    }

    .propGrid .x-grid-header-ct{ 
        border: 0px;

        border-top: 0.5px solid black;
        border-bottom: 0.5px solid black;


        padding: 0px;
    }

    .propGrid .x-grid-header-ct .x-box-inner{ 
        border: 0px;

        border-top: 0.5px solid black;
        border-bottom: 0.5px solid black;
        border-right: thin solid black;

        padding: 0px;
    }

    .propGrid .x-grid-header-ct .x-box-inner .x-column-header-inner{ 
        border: 0px;

        border-top: 0.5px solid black;
        border-bottom: 0.5px solid black;
        border-left: thin solid black;
        background: lightgray;
        -webkit-print-color-adjust:exact;

        padding: 0px;
        margin: 0px;

        font-size: 11px; 
        font-weight: bold;
        font-family: 'Arial';
        text-align: center;
    }
}
```

I also think that I have overlapping CSS Properties in my Property Grid but I've had bad experiences with CSS so I'm not changing it since it's working pretty decently.

Here is my grid panel code:

```
            {
                xtype: 'gridpanel',
                x: 50,
                y: 240,
                border: '1 1 1 1',
                cls: 'receiptGrid',
                height: 120,
                itemId: 'pfGridPanelItems',
                maxHeight: 120,
                maxWidth: 500,
                minHeight: 120,
                minWidth: 500,
                padding: 0,
                style: 'border: 0.5;\nborder-color: black;',
                width: 500,
                bodyBorder: true,
                bodyPadding: 0,
                header: false,
                title: 'My Grid Panel',
                syncRowHeight: false,
                columnLines: true,
                enableColumnHide: false,
                enableColumnMove: false,
                enableColumnResize: false,
                rowLines: false,
                scroll: 'none',
                sealedColumns: true,
                sortableColumns: false,
                store: 'pfReceipt',
                columns: [
                    {
                        xtype: 'gridcolumn',
                        height: 30,
                        maxHeight: 30,
                        maxWidth: 100,
                        minHeight: 30,
                        minWidth: 100,
                        style: 'background: pink !important;',
                        width: 100,
                        dataIndex: 'description',
                        emptyCellText: 'PF',
                        text: 'DESCRIPTION',
                        flex: 1
                    },
                    {
                        xtype: 'datecolumn',
                        height: 30,
                        itemId: 'date',
                        maxHeight: 30,
                        maxWidth: 100,
                        minHeight: 30,
                        minWidth: 100,
                        width: 100,
                        dataIndex: 'date',
                        text: 'DATE',
                        flex: 1,
                        editor: {
                            xtype: 'datefield',
                            itemId: 'dateField',
                            margin: '9 0 0 0',
                            fieldLabel: 'Date',
                            hideLabel: true,
                            value: '2014-11-01',
                            emptyText: 'mm-dd-yyyy',
                            format: 'Y-m-d',
                            submitFormat: 'Y-m-d'
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        xtype: 'gridcolumn',
                        height: 30,
                        maxHeight: 30,
                        maxWidth: 100,
                        minHeight: 30,
                        minWidth: 100,
                        width: 100,
                        dataIndex: 'check',
                        text: 'CHECK',
                        flex: 1,
                        editor: {
                            xtype: 'textfield',
                            height: '100%',
                            width: '100%',
                            allowBlank: false,
                            allowOnlyWhitespace: false,
                            emptyText: 'Check No.'
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        xtype: 'gridcolumn',
                        height: 30,
                        maxHeight: 30,
                        maxWidth: 100,
                        minHeight: 30,
                        minWidth: 100,
                        width: 100,
                        dataIndex: 'bank',
                        text: 'BANK',
                        flex: 1,
                        editor: {
                            xtype: 'textfield',
                            height: '100%',
                            width: '100%',
                            emptyText: 'Bank'
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        xtype: 'numbercolumn',
                        height: 30,
                        maxHeight: 30,
                        maxWidth: 100,
                        minHeight: 30,
                        minWidth: 100,
                        shrinkWrap: 0,
                        width: 100,
                        dataIndex: 'amount',
                        text: 'AMOUNT',
                        flex: 1,
                        editor: {
                            xtype: 'textfield',
                            height: '100%',
                            itemId: 'mytextfield5',
                            shrinkWrap: 0,
                            width: '100%',
                            emptyText: 'Amount',
                            enableKeyEvents: true
                        }
                    }
                ],
                viewConfig: {
                    getRowClass: function(record, rowIndex, rowParams, store) {
                        return 'child-row';
                    },
                    border: '1 1 1 1',
                    itemId: 'pfReceiptGrid'
                },
                plugins: [
                    Ext.create('Ext.grid.plugin.CellEditing', {

                    })
                ]
            },
```

and here is my property Grid

```
            {
                xtype: 'propertygrid',
                x: 570,
                y: 210,
                border: '1 1 1 1',
                cls: 'propGrid',
                itemId: 'pfGridPanelMode',
                maxWidth: 200,
                minWidth: 200,
                width: 200,
                bodyBorder: true,
                frameHeader: false,
                header: false,
                title: 'Payment Mode',
                scroll: 'none',
                sealedColumns: true,
                sortableColumns: false,
                source: {
                    CASH: 0,
                    CHECK: 0,
                    TOTAL: 0
                },
                sourceConfig: {
                    //huge block of sourceConfig code here
                }
            }
```

I am using Sencha Architect so I do not have an html file.

Can anyone help me how to make the right and bottom borders display during Print Preview? Any help will be very much appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: an example of the error with your HTML would be very helpfull to help you

Comment: I am not getting an error in the sense that the code isn't running. I am using Sencha Architect so I do not have an html file.

Comment: I never heard of `Sencha Architect`, I can't help on this, you didn't mention that in your question previously. I suggest you add its tag to the question and wait someone who knows it...